# In kettle use text file input read csv file from a tar.gz file but it didn't worked. Where it might be wrong?

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a csv file that is tared and zipped. So I have test.tar.gz.
I would like, through text file input, read csv file.
I try this **`tar:gz:file://C:/test/test.tar.gz!/test.tar!`**  use wildcard like **`".*\.csv"`**.
But it sometime can't read success.
It throws Exception

```
 org.apache.commons.vfs.FileNotFolderException: 
 Could not list the contents of 
 "tar:gz:file:///C:/test/test.tar.gz!/test.tar!/" 
  because it is not a folder.
```

I use windows8.1, pdi 5.2
Where it might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a compressed file csv reading, "Text File Input" step in Pentaho Kettle only supports the first files inside the compressed folder(either in Zip/GZip file). Check the [Pentaho Wiki](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Text+File+Input) in the compression section.

Now for your issue, try **removing the wildcard entry** since only the first file inside the zip/gzip file will be read. *(as explained above)*

I have placed a sample code containing both reading zip and gzip files. Check it [here](https://gist.github.com/rishuatgithub/96481b4ba84288703f41).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your help.I found that if i don't click the Preview button, it Will not throw exception.Thanks again.

Comment: @peijd thanks :).. yes it will throw exception while previewing since you are trying to execute the linux zip file on a windows machine. :) !! What i did in my sample code above, i manually entered the field names and then executed (using the .tar) file, it worked !!

Comment: I tested  found that don't click the Preview button,it will work. but if it have one time throw exception,it will not work. you need restart spoon, and you can click the "get fields" button  in the field tab, When run it might throw an exception.but restart it,rerun it,  it will work.

Comment: @peijd ohh great !! Didn't try restarting the spoon!! Then it might be some bug i assume??